# Location.hash causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html

I am using location.hash in javascript, to allow the user to switch between ajax screens (divs that are added and removed dynamically within the same html page).

The problem is, when I update location.hash by javascript, the window listener immediately fires! I need this event to fire only when the back button is actually clicked, not when I change the history by javascript.

My window listener code:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    var s;   
    if (location.hash.length > 0) {        
       s = parseInt(location.hash.replace('#',''),10);     
    } else {
       s = 1;
    }
    main.showScreen(s);
}
```

And my screen update code:

```
main.showScreen = function(i) {
    // allow the back button to switch between screens
    location.hash = i;
    // but setting location.hash causes this same function to fire again!
    //
    // here follows the code that adds a new div with new text content
    // ...
}
```

To clarify: showScreen can be called from anywhere in the application, for example by clicking a "next" button somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In your main.showScreen function, you can:

```
if (location.hash != i)
  location.hash = i;
```

OR, you can set up a document-scoped variable with the last hash value.

```
var lastHash = -1;
window.onhashchange = function() {
    var s;   
    if (location.hash.length > 0) {        
       s = parseInt(location.hash.replace('#',''),10);     
    } else {
       s = 1;
    }

    if (lastHash != s) {
      lastHash = s;
      main.showScreen(s);
    }
}
```